# Label truncation while using Grouped category plugin in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

1. When a very long string is passed as category to grouped category plugin used at highcharts, it appends the label with ellipsis as shown below

[image]

2. but when i replace the variables with spaces, it starts adding carriage return instead of actually replacing with ellipsis as shown below.

[image]

Is there a way to actually make 2 consistent to be with 1?

Comment: try staggerlines in xAxis: label

Comment: adding staggerlines and setting whitespace style to nowrap fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding staggerlines in xAxis: label would fix this issue.